# GNSS SDR shows incorrect longitude value from GPS-SDR sim signal

Tags: gps

When I use GPS-SDR Sim ephemeris and location coordinates (Shangai) from example I get correct values for  lat,lng,alt. When I move coordinates around 500m from default location I also get correct values. But when I change coordinates to other side of the world I get correct lat, but longitude and altitude around zero. If I am correct, ephemeris data should work for any coordinate on earth?

this is default location:

`gps-sdr-sim -e brdc3540.14n -l 30.286502,120.032669,100`

this is the closer one which works fine:

`gps-sdr-sim -e brdc3540.14n -l 30.302334,120.036939,100`

this one is incorrect:

`gps-sdr-sim -e brdc3540.14n -l 44.572710, 12.298724, 10`

I use GNSS-SDR as receiver which takes above generated .bin .

EDIT:

Turns out, solution was to use different ephemeris file (brdc file). Still, I would say it should work on any daily ephemeris file downloaded, which is currently not true.

Answer (score -1):

what are the IF and sampling frequency and data type of the IF file generated from gps sdr sim. I want to use GNSS SDR but unable to use it.  Thank you

Comment: please ask a new question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) if you need help.